How to extract posterior estimates from brm() fit
I basically fit a brm() fit and I want to extract the esimates (related to all itearions) of all covariates for mu, hu and shape formula.
My fit is as follows:
fit_hnb2 <- brm(bf(count_formula, zero_formula, shape_formula),
               data = data_hnb, 
               family = hurdle_negbinomial(link = "log", link_shape = "log", link_hu = "logit"),
               refresh = 0)

I know that I can extract estimates like below:
formula_para<-as.data.frame(fit, variable = "^b_",regex = TRUE)
  hu_para<-as.data.frame(fit, variable = "^b_hu_",regex = TRUE)
  rm_col<-colnames(hu_para)
  count_para<-formula_para[, !(colnames(formula_para) %in% rm_col), drop = FALSE]

But I want to know if there is a way to extract these estimates without hard coding like "b_". Incase they change the prefix to some other (eg: "beta_"), I will also have to change my code.

Please post a small data sample.  Next: you generate fit_hnb2 but then operate on something named fit  Please edit as necessary to clarify what's happening.

Basically,  that is not a good way to go about it.  I'd recommend something like
formula_para <- fit$coefficients[c(grep('beta',rownames(fit$coeffients))),]
But to your question: people who write packages don't randomly change names, be they list elements, rownames, columnnames, etc., so your concern about future name changes is really unwarranted.
